# How to refresh the fragment after setting new data? The data can be retrieved, yet after setting new contact, it can't automatically update

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, refresh

I wanted to refresh fragment every time when database is updated. The Set contact and save it to database is working well, data can be retrieved as well. Yet, everytime when I tried to set new contact, the database updated, but the retrieving part wont update. It can only be updated after I switched to other fragment or activity.

//java class file

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener, OnMenuItemLongClickListener { 

private final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextView mTxtToolbarTitle;

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private ContextMenuDialogFragment mMenuDialogFragment;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private Button btn_msgD;
private String eName,eTel,userID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.appbar_color));
    }
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    initToolBar();
    initMenuFragment();
    addFragment(new Fragment_US(), true, R.id.fragment);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

    displayUserInfo();
}
```

//button intent to another page

```
    public void initMyAccount(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, MyAccount.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

//button Set Contact

```
    public void initSetEmergencyContact(View view){
    Intent it = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(it,PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

//get data from database and display in textView

```
    public void displayUserInfo(){

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot users:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot user:users.getChildren())
                {
                    if (user.getKey().equals(userID))
                    {
                        for (DataSnapshot EmergencyContact:user.getChildren())
                        {
                            if (EmergencyContact.getKey().equals("EmergencyContact"))
                            {
                                EmergencyContact ec = EmergencyContact.getValue(EmergencyContact.class);
                                TextView uInfoTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_kNameTV);
                                TextView uInfoTV2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_kNoTV);
                                uInfoTV.setText(ec.getkName());
                                uInfoTV2.setText(ec.getkTel());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(reqCode)
    {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber =phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        String nameContact = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String numContact = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        eName = nameContact;
                        eTel = numContact;

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameContact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        EmergencyContact eCon = new EmergencyContact(eName,eTel);
                        eCon.setkName(eName);
                        eCon.setkTel(eTel);
                        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        databaseReference.child("users").child(userID).child("EmergencyContact").setValue(eCon);
                        //editText.setText(nameContact+ " "+ cNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

//fragment Content

```
    private void initMenuFragment() {

    MenuParams menuParams = new MenuParams();
    menuParams.setActionBarSize((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tool_bar_height));
    menuParams.setMenuObjects(getMenuObjects());
    menuParams.setClosableOutside(false);
    mMenuDialogFragment = ContextMenuDialogFragment.newInstance(menuParams);
    mMenuDialogFragment.setItemClickListener(this);
    mMenuDialogFragment.setItemLongClickListener(this);
}

private List<MenuObject> getMenuObjects() {

    List<MenuObject> menuObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    MenuObject close = new MenuObject();
    close.setResource(R.drawable.icn_close);

    MenuObject accPage = new MenuObject("UserProfile");
    accPage.setResource(R.drawable.icn_3);

    MenuObject chat = new MenuObject("PPChat");
    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icn_1));
    chat.setDrawable(bd);

    MenuObject contact = new MenuObject("ContactDoctor");
    contact.setResource(R.drawable.icn_4);

    menuObjects.add(close);
    menuObjects.add(accPage);
    menuObjects.add(chat);
    menuObjects.add(contact);
    return menuObjects;
}
```

//Toolbar

```
    private void initToolBar() {

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    mTxtToolbarTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    //mTxtToolbarTitle.setText("");
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.btn_back);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (UserProfile.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    mTxtToolbarTitle.setText("User Profile");
}

protected void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, int containerId) {

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    String backStackName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStackName, 0);
    if (!fragmentPopped) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(containerId, fragment, backStackName)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        if (addToBackStack)
            transaction.addToBackStack(backStackName);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.context_menu:
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG) == null) {
                mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on position: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mMenuDialogFragment != null && mMenuDialogFragment.isAdded()) {
        mMenuDialogFragment.dismiss();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

//fragment position

```
    @Override
public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    if(position == 1){
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, UserProfile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if(position == 2){
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, PPChat.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if(position == 3){
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, ContactDoctor.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMenuItemLongClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Long clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every action that can last than 5 seconds and cause ANR you need to execute in separate thread by using Service or IntentService. After that you update your information in the view with the use of class from the extension ResultReceiver.

Here is an example how I am doing it:

Fragment from which you request data from DB:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_statistics)
public class StatisticsFragment extends Fragment {

DbResultReceiver dbResultReceiver;

final static String TAG = "Debug_StatFragment";

class DbResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Debug_DbResultReceiver";

    DbResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Result code : " + resultCode);

        switch(resultCode){
            case AppConstants.RESULT_CURRENT_WEEK :
                writeRows(resultData);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@ViewById(R.id.tv_ex_stat)
TextView tvExampleText;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach()");

    // Register receiver for get response from intent service
    dbResultReceiver = new DbResultReceiver(new Handler());

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting service.. ");

    refreshStatistics();
}


private void refreshStatistics(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing statistics table .. ");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DbIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_GET_WEEK_DATA);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_INTENT_RESULT, dbResultReceiver);
    getActivity().startService(intent);
}

private void writeRows(Bundle data){

    Log.d(TAG, "Writing rows..");

    int rowCount = data.getInt(EXTRAS_DB_ROWS_COUNT);
    String text = "";

    Log.d(TAG, "amount of rows: " + rowCount);

    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
        text += "Date : " + data.getString(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_DATE + i) +
                "Amount : " + data.getLong(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_AMOUNT + i) +
                "Drunk : " + data.getDouble(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_DRUNK + i) + "\n";

    }

    tvExampleText.setText(text);
}
```

}

And the actual IntentService :

```
public class DbIntentService extends IntentService {

private Intent mIntent;
private DbAdapter db;

private Bundle data = null;

private static final String TAG = "Debug_DBIntentService";

public DbIntentService() {
    super(DbIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    Log.d(TAG, "Start thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    db = new DbAdapter(this);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent()");

    int resultCode;
    mIntent = intent;

//      Open connection with DB
    Log.d(TAG, "Opening database..");
    db.open();

//      Proceed request to the database
    resultCode = proceedRequest(mIntent.getAction());

//      Close connection with DB
    Log.d(TAG, "Closing database..");
    db.close();

//      Sending result back to an Activity
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending result back to an activity..");
    sendResult(resultCode, data);
}


private int proceedRequest(String action){
    switch (action){
        case ACTION_IS_CURRENT_DAY:
            return isCurrentDay();
        case ACTION_GET_DAY_DATA :
            return getCurrentDayData();
        case ACTION_GET_WEEK_DATA :
            return getCurrentWeekData();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

/* Get the data for the current week */
private int getCurrentWeekData(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Getting data for the week..");

    Cursor rows = db.getCurWeekRows();

    int rowsCount = rows.getCount();
    Bundle weekData = new Bundle();

    int count = 0;
    weekData.putInt(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_ROWS_COUNT, rowsCount);

    if(rows.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            weekData.putString(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_DATE + count, rows.getString(0));
            weekData.putLong(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_AMOUNT + count, rows.getLong(1));
            weekData.putDouble(AppConstants.EXTRAS_DB_DRUNK + count, rows.getDouble(2));

            Log.d(TAG, "ROW [" + count + "]  date : " + rows.getString(0) + " amount : " + rows.getLong(1) + " drink : "+ rows.getDouble(2));

            count++;
        }
        while(rows.moveToNext());
    }

    data = weekData;
    return AppConstants.RESULT_CURRENT_WEEK;
}

private void sendResult(int resultCode, Bundle data){
    ResultReceiver resultReceiver = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS_INTENT_RESULT);
    if(resultReceiver != null) {
        resultReceiver.send(resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```